# JQL query to filter JIRAs based on the last commented date by a particular account / user

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin, jql

I am new to JIRA / JQL, and wanted help in knowing if the following is possible:

- I want to filter JIRAs which have been commented on by a particular user (a bot account) in the past xx days
- I want to filter JIRAs which have a particular regex in its comments in the past xx days

If the above cannot be done, I am open to suggestions as to how to achieve it using a combination of labels and description in the JIRA!

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, but comments are stored within each Issue and you can't search for them globally using the native JQL query. You'd need to utilise the REST API to iterate through the Issues, extracting all the comments, then filtering the results.

Refer to [this article in the Atlassian community Jira blog](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/JQL-query-for-comments-for-particular-user/qaq-p/82024) on the same topic and what third party tools can help work around the issue.

Answer (score -1):

```
project = project and issueFunction in commented("by lpellet after -2d")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Comment: Actually `issueFunction` requires buying a ScriptRunner plug-in, it is not a standard JQL function.